# iPhone: Image on iOS 6 is showing blurred?

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have an image named abc.png of size 320 by 156 which runs well on iPhone 4 and an image named as abc@2x.png of size 640 by 312 which also works fine. but when Please enlighten me on how to use the image for the iPhone 6 device?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is nothing like iPhone6 as of now, it is either iOS6 or iPhone 5. 
But I guess you are talking about iPhone 5 with screen resolution 640X1136.
There is no in-built way to select image for iPhone 5.

if you have abc.png and abc@2x.png in resources , and you use a code like:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
```

it will pick abc.png for non-retina display and abc@2x.png for retina display(that includes iPhone 4S and iPhone 5).

If you want to load separate image for iPhone 5, you will need to check the screen height:

```
if(screenHeight == 480)
{
 //iphone 3,3G,4
}
else if(screenHeight == 960)
{
//iphone 4S 
}
else if(screenHeight == 1136)
{
//iphone 5
}
```

This way you may load different images for different iphones.
Please uprate and check the answer if it answers ur question.

Comment: is this thing valid for the simulator of ios6. i am using the code: [UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame].size.height==568 to check the height of simulator

Comment: [UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame].size.height and screenHeight i am using are same..... Just that I have taken into account the scale.... scale value for non retina display =1; for retina display =2

Comment: iPhone 4 has a retina display, so it has the same screenHeight as the iPhone 4S

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question, I'm afraid to say, is something called `AutoLayout`. That's the solution Apple came up with to deal with the different form factor for iOS 6 views. Only `@2x` images are available, but with `AutoLayout`, you can tell it exactly how to behave.

Here's a nice tutorial on how to use `AutoLayout`, I tried it and it works well:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2